# Magento, adding an item to basket then checking out as guest or register redirects back to the basket

Tags: magento, shopping-cart

This has had me stumped for quite some time now.
My site www.butterflywish.co.uk

Whenever I add any item to my basket then checkout either as a guest or register, it goes through to the next page in the buying process then redirects me back to the shopping cart page almost instantly.

I have tried cleaning the cache, altering the php memory size, and various other suggestions from other posts with no joy.

If somebody is able to help it would be most appreciated.

Comment: I went through and placed a test order ..  # 100000019 ---  Here is the confirmation page http://s9.postimg.org/uufiyvijz/confirm.png   ..  This may be a browser issue .. What browser are you using?